# ElasticSearch cluster down due to high memory usage

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform

I have ran some queries on ES, which fetched huge amount of data and due to that Memory utilization reached high and ES cluster went down.
Below is the error that ES-java client has thrown

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"circuit_breaking_exception","reason":"[parent] Data too large, data for [<http_request>] would be [4031859746/3.7gb], which is larger than the limit of [3865051136/3.5gb], real usage: [4031859168/3.7gb], new bytes reserved: [578/578b], usages [model_inference=0/0b, inflight_requests=47776/46.6kb, request=1290403896/1.2gb, fielddata=340509/332.5kb, eql_sequence=0/0b]","bytes_wanted":4031859746,"bytes_limit":3865051136,"durability":"TRANSIENT"}],"type":"circuit_breaking_exception","reason":"[parent] Data too large, data for [<http_request>] would be [4031859746/3.7gb], which is larger than the limit of [3865051136/3.5gb], real usage: [4031859168/3.7gb], new bytes reserved: [578/578b], usages [model_inference=0/0b, inflight_requests=47776/46.6kb, request=1290403896/1.2gb, fielddata=340509/332.5kb, eql_sequence=0/0b]","bytes_wanted":4031859746,"bytes_limit":3865051136,"durability":"TRANSIENT"},"status":429}
```

in ES node found below logs for this where GC not able to bring memory usage down

```
[2023-07-06T07:44:51,220][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [es-1.com] [gc][9226168] overhead, spent [563ms] collecting in the last [1s]
[2023-07-06T07:50:43,768][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [es-1.com] [gc][9226520] overhead, spent [852ms] collecting in the last [1.1s]
[2023-07-06T07:50:44,368][INFO ][o.e.i.b.HierarchyCircuitBreakerService] [es-1.com] attempting to trigger G1GC due to high heap usage [3870694016]
[2023-07-06T07:50:44,375][INFO ][o.e.i.b.HierarchyCircuitBreakerService] [es-1.com] GC did not bring memory usage down, before [3870694016], after [3885846280], allocations [1], duration [7]
[2023-07-06T07:50:45,153][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [es-1.com] [gc][9226521] overhead, spent [1.2s] collecting in the last [1.4s]
[2023-07-06T07:50:46,291][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [es-1.com] [gc][9226522] overhead, spent [1.1s] collecting in the last [1.1s]
[2023-07-06T07:51:21,814][WARN ][o.e.t.ThreadPool         ] [es-1.com] timer thread slept for [30.2s/30283ms] on absolute clock which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]
```

There are 3 VM nodes in ES cluster and each node is having all roles. My ES clusters node roles are like this:

```
cdfhilmrstw
cdfhilmrstw
cdfhilmrstw
```

I am using VM of GCP. for this VM auto-matic restart is on. please check below image.
[image]

Not able to understand why ES VM went down due to this? is there any configuration through which instead of shut-down, VM get restarted for such scenarios? so that it don't impact production traffic.

Comment: The area in your image's red circle does not apply to your problem. Those settings are for when Google performs system maintenance. Your problem is an HTTP request of `4031859746/3.7gb`.